# How can i change the key of the array with the value of the same array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

This is the result of my array:

```
array(3) {
  [968]=>
  string(12) "TRALALAA0"
  [918]=>
  string(23) "TRALALAA1"
  [912]=>
  string(66) "TRALALAA2"
}
```

I want that output would be:

```
 array(3) {
      ['TRALALAA0']=>
      string(12) "968"
      ['TRALALAA1']=>
      string(23) "918"
      ['TRALALAA0']=>
      string(66) "912"
    }
```

Is there a function to do that stuff in PHP ?

Comment: Using the [array_flip()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = array_flip($array);
```

This function flips the keys with the values

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**array_flip**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) for this.

```
$valsAsKeys = array_flip($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

the function is called
[array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `array_flip()`

```
$arr = array_flip($arr);
```

More details here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php